# Designing clustering results in RapidMiner Studio 6.1

Tags: cluster-analysis, rapidminer

My process is (Process Documents from Files  -> K-Means clustering). "Folder View" clustering results shows only filenames within each cluster.

Questions:
1) How to organize process to show content of text files instead of filenames? My texts are short. How to export that view?
2) How to organize process to read documents from single file line by line (each text line is document) instead of "Process Documents from Files"?

Regards,

Comment: Are you tokenizing inside the `Process Documents from Files` operator?

Comment: Sure, I tokenize and more... inside "Process Documents from Files". The output is very valid. I'm just asking about the presentation of Clustering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `keep text` check box on the `Process Documents` operator, the original text will accompany the attributes corresponding to the tokenized text.